# Updating internal fieldname not getting reflected

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, content-type, custom-field-types, content-type-hub

Here's my scenario : Created a content type hub and programmatically created a custom content type and added a custom field in it. Solution got deployed successfully.

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint">
<ContentType ID="0x010008F15D6B2D0A454BA95AA5D91E21416E" 
             Name="MyCustomContentType" 
             Group="JL" 
             Description="This is my custom content type">    
<FieldRefs>      
     <FieldRef ID="{4e6a1cad-d0e4-4ce2-9086-8664cbb6ef73}" Name="CustomChoice" />
</FieldRefs>  
</ContentType>
<Field ID="{4e6a1cad-d0e4-4ce2-9086-8664cbb6ef73}" 
       Name="CustomChoice" 
       DisplayName="Custom Choice Column" 
       Type="Choice" 
       StaticName="CustomChoice" 
       DisplaceOnUpgrade="TRUE" 
       Group="JL">
<CHOICES>
        <CHOICE>Choice 1</CHOICE>
        <CHOICE>Choice 2</CHOICE>
</CHOICES>
</Field>
</Elements>
```

However, i had to change the internal name of the field. So when i modified the internal name of the field in the schema and deployed the solution, the column in content type hub modified. But if i create a new site collection subscribing the content type hub it still refers the old internal value.

Here's my modification

```
<Field ID="{4e6a1cad-d0e4-4ce2-9086-8664cbb6ef73}" 
       Name="CustomChoice_01" 
       DisplayName="Custom Choice Column" 
       Type="Choice"
```

Comment: You also must Publish the changes from the Content Type hub

Comment: Thanks Robert. I already published the changes from Content Type hub